Windows midi+Bluetooth reconnection issue

midi keyboard that works only via bluetooth (Pop-piano MP228)
bluetooth adapter for PC Ugreen 5.3
Windows 11
Midiberry

Everything works fine in Midiberry with a fairly low latency, but every 20 seconds the midi keyboard returns from the connected mode to the paired mode. I have to restart Midiberry. At first I thought that the problem was that WindowsOS was constantly trying to get the charge level of the midi keyboard, but I tried to see what was happening in Bluetooth LE Explorer, if I log into the device through this program, it also loses the connection (every 30 seconds), but literally for a split second and again in the Connected mode, there you can see that the Value line continues to change. I also tried Midiberry on Windows 10, the breaks are even more frequent, literally every 5 seconds and I need to restart Midiberry, is it really impossible to disable it in Windows so that it does not check the battery of the connected device.
Is it possible to make Midiberry not lose the connection state?
upd:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-midibluetooth-reconnection-issue/f246877c-5cc1-401f-bed2-fe33d00fbe7d
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Se_FV0VR-Ig&lc=Ugyp0GGqV64jt0RVAKB4AaABAg

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
